How can I remove unnecessary software stores?
I have three stores on my computer. The Ubuntu Software store, the Snap Store, and the Gnome Software store. How can I consolidate these? The Ubuntu software store just opens to the Snap store when I click it. A while ago I installed Flatpack support and now I have three stores. I'm trying to clean things up and make it like the default installation. I am running Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish 22.04.4 LTS. Also, when the point release for Noble Numbat is released will it install another store?
I have attached a picture of my Dock icons below for reference. The orange icon is the "Ubuntu Software store", the white one is the "Gnome Software Store" and the blue one with the bird is the "Snap Store".
Thanks!


Thanks, would removing Flatpack remove one of the stores I listed. From what I was able to find, the debian and snap store are supposed to get replaced by the Ubuntu store. Or is it something else?

There are two stores (deb and snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 and 24.04. I've not heard about Ubuntu store.

I just updated the post with more information. From what you've said so far it seems like the Ubuntu store is just a Skin for the Snap store and Debian is separate. It that correct?

@Mahler No, Snap is also optional. One can have a perfectly working Ubuntu installation without snap. You cannot have a working Ubuntu installation without deb packages

@ChaseSimmons Can you confirm if you can access snaps from gnome software?

Hello, I can access snaps from the gnome software store. It does everything that the Ubuntu store does. What confused me was that the Ubuntu store just opens the Snap store. I can't just access the snap store directly.

When I open the Gnome Software store it opens separately.
